# Grep continually returning 0 when called from python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Background: I have a lot of music. I also tend to listen to the same albums over and over. Eventually, this annoyed me to the point where I decided I'd listen to a different one each day. Seeing as I have just over 100 albums in my collection, and seeing as I know a little programming, I thought I'd write a script to help myself out.

Now, keep in mind, I'm a student who knows he knows very little. Most of what I know has been from a single Python book (though a decent one for getting beginners off the ground) and the Python documentation.

Also, I'm running Python 3.6 and using Cygwin, so I do have *nix commands available.

The problem lies in the following method (edit 9:43 EST - suggested "if line in file" implementation added; new lines starred):

```
def choose_album(library_file, day_file):
    albums = []
    for line in fileinput.input(library_file):
        albums.append(line)
    fileinput.close() #**
    check_file = io.open(day_file) #**
    album_chosen = False #**
    while album_chosen == False:
        choice = random.randrange(0, len(albums))
        print("Searching for " + albums[choice] + ".")
        for line in check_file: #**
            if albums[choice] in line: #**
                break #**
        if albums[choice] not in check_file: #**
            album_chosen = True #**
    print(albums[choice])
    return albums[choice]
```

where the library_file is a text file with all of the albums I have purchased or listened to on Spotify and the day_file is my "album of the day" file, each line containing a date and the album for that day.
The while loop used to be an

```
if albums[choice] in line:
    break
```

and then the script would go on to write that to the day_file.
It worked fine, but the problem was that the `if albums[choice] in line` line would sometimes return false negatives, giving me an album I'd already listened to, meaning I'd have to go back into my file, delete the redundant album, and run the script again.

Update (9:43 EST) Based on my test run of the edited code, this at least doesn't spit out heaps of text. Is it likely to give me duplicates again?

Update (12:02 EST) - removed output that became irrelevant due to suggestion.

Comment: You should be getting `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'`. Is this your exact code?

Comment: "if albums[choice] in line line would sometimes return false negatives": what? have you analysed? because it works. No need for grep, which will choke on regex special characters.

Comment: @WilliamPursell `run` exists in subprocess module from version 3.5

Comment: Does this occur if you replace `grep` with a full path (eg `/usr/bin/grep`).  Which grep is first in your path?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre hmm, then obviously I had done something else wrong, because it would sometimes give me duplicates. Now, unfortunately, I can't show you exactly what the code used to look like; I don't have a previous version.

Comment: I don't see the difference between "in" and "grep" without word boundary options. Can't you recreate the old version and {edit] your question? because running grep from python is just a waste of space.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I should be able to. I'll let you know when I've done that.

Comment: yes, you do that. I'll wait.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre edited version is up

Comment: The title and some of the diagnostics no longer make much sense. I was desperately looking for the `subprocess` code but it's been edited out. Could you please revise and [edit] so it's a coherent whole? (We sometimes delete things so we can edit them into shape and then undelete, but perhaps there is a rep limit you haven't yet crossed.)

Comment: There's a newline at the end of the printed album name which causes at least my `grep` on Mac OS to print all lines of the input file.

Comment: @tripleee That's because grep was part of my inital code. As per Jean-François Fabre's sugesstion, I've changed the code to NOT use grep. I will change the title accordingly if needed, though I might just request that the question be closed if the issue doesn't come up again.

Comment: Maybe still worth noting the explanation: `grep` apparently treats `grep $'foo\n' file` like `grep -e 'foo' -e '' file`, i.e. if a line contains "foo" or "anything" (an empty substing partially matches every input string) then it's a successful match. You could work around this with `grep -Fx` but of course the proper fix is to trim the newline (and then just use Python to scan the file anyway, as other have already persuaded you).

Comment: As another tangential comment, think about making your data file both machine- and human-readable. JSON is one common popular representation format for data which  is reasonably easy to read, yet easy to load back into a program without (explicit) additional parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading lines without trimming the final newline:

```
for line in fileinput.input(library_file):
    albums.append(line)  ##### BUG
```

What you probably *meant* to write might be along the lines of

```
    albums.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

The newline caused `grep` to print out every line. Somewhat to my surprise, after 25+ years as an active Unix user, I discovered that at least some versions of `grep` will cause

```
 grep 'String which ends with newline
 ' filename
```

to print out every line in `filename`, apparently because it considers this equivalent to

```
grep -e 'String which ends with newline' -e '' filename`
```

where obviously the empty string as a regular expression matches every possible input.

Switching from `grep` to `if albums[choice] in line` removes this symptom, and actually happens to work because you are also not trimming newlines from lines you read from the other file, and you specifically look for matches which are at the end of the line; and so `"foo\n" in "datestamp foo\n"` actually returns `True`.  However, this appears to be contrary to your expectations (for example, you are printing the string followed by a full stop, which lands after the embedded newline, on a line by itself in the output) so perhaps this is still a (minor) bug in your code.